# TextField subview not resizing w/ UITableViewCell frame size change

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Have a storyboard w/ a TableViewController that has a grouped table view. In the first section, I want the cells' width to be smaller than full-screen. To accomplish the latter, I have a custom UITableViewCell class w/ the following method:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += NAME_TABLE_VIEW_INSET;
    frame.size.width -= NAME_TABLE_VIEW_INSET;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

That works fine. The issue I have is that a UITextField subview that I dragged into the storyboard cell does not adjust its width automatically to the new cell frame size.

I've tried sub-classing UITextField and ensuring that the autoResizingMask is set properly, and I've tried using [super layoutSubviews] in the setFrame method above. None of these approaches works.

Any suggestions on how I can get the text field to adjust its width automatically while still using this storyboard approach?

Comment: are you using `Contraints` (i.e. `autoLayout` is enabled in your storyboard)? Have you tried manually adjusting the `UITextField`; if you have created a custom class, `IBOutlet` the `UITextField` and then your `setFrame` can adjust it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. yes, contraints enabled in storyboard. i'll take a look at setFrame on the outlets instead. will see.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to add a separate table view in the header of the tableView provided by the table view controller. Specifically, add a view object to the top of the table view in IB; add a table view as a subview into that view; change the width of the new table view's cells.

Note that this problem exists only because I wanted to use a table view controller, which defaults each cell to the width of the screen. A view controller could have been used, but then you cannot add a table view w/ static cells as a subview.